# Matching container or stage scale to mouse event coordinates in easelJs

Tags: canvas, zooming, easeljs

Just getting started on my first easelJs project and I am having a little trouble understanding what is happening with my attempt at zoom + drag'n drop.

If you look at the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wDcvfgnq6ujYStQv4N79?p=preview) you can see I have a simple zoom factor affected by mouse wheel

```
  function MouseWheelHandler(mouseWheelEvent) {
    if (Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (mouseWheelEvent.wheelDelta || -mouseWheelEvent.detail))) > 0) {
      zoom = 1.1;
    } else {
      zoom = 1 / 1.1;
    }
    container.scaleX = container.scaleY *= zoom;
    gravesStage.update();
  }
```

Then I create a circle, and attempt to drag it around using evt.stage coordinates.

```
  circle.on("pressmove",
    function(evt) {
      evt.target.x = evt.stageX * zoom;
      evt.target.y = evt.stageY * zoom;
```

I just can't seem to get this calculation right though. It seems to take the mouse relative to the canvas, instead of considering the zoom.
Is anyone able to explain to me the issue here?

Thanks,
Brian

[>> Plunkr here <<](http://plnkr.co/edit/wDcvfgnq6ujYStQv4N79?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! I should have been more persistent before asking...

Solution:

```
  evt.target.x = evt.stageX / container.scaleX;
  evt.target.y = evt.stageY / container.scaleY;
```

The issue was that the zoom was the incremental scaling amount, but what I really needed to do was scale the new X/Y value but the scale of the stage/container instead.

Comment: You can also use `event.localX` and `event.localY` to get the mouse coordinates inside the scaled clip.